# How can I use "HMVC" in kohana phpframework?

Tags: php, kohana, hmvc

I have a project want to use kohana framework, and the composition of this project like:

test1 (this is one module in my project)
    classes
        controller
        model
    views

test2 (this is the other module in my project)
    classes
        controller
        model
    views

....more

I want urls like this:
http://example.com/test1/controller/action/...
http://example.com/test2/controller/action/...

How can I do that?

Comment: Whats the quistion? Do you want to define target module via URL? Have you read http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/files and http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the basic Kohana structure but with two application folders instead of one:

```
test1
    application
    index.php
test2
    application
    index.php
modules
system
```

Both test1 and test2 would share the modules and system directories.

Then just make sure to update the application, modules and system path in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose to do two sites:
/var/www/sites/site1/
and
/var/www/sites/site2/

Then set modules and system-dirs to /var/www/kohana/system and /var/www/kohana/modules
and just change the SYSDIR/MODDIR-variables in bootstrap.php to respective dirs.

good luck!